# C++ template parameters as arguments to assembler macros in an asm block (gcc/gas)

Tags: c++, assembly, macros, arm

I am attempting to use an integer template argument in some asm macros, but I'm running into a substitution problem.  Below is a (very) simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
template<int X> void delay() {
    asm __volatile__(
        "  .macro fl_delay dtime, reg=r0    \n\t"
        "    .if (\\dtime > 0)              \n\t"
        "      .set dcycle, (\\dtime / 3)   \n\t"
        "      .set dwork, (dcycle * 3)     \n\t"
        "      .set drem, (\\dtime - dwork) \n\t"
        "      .rept (drem)                 \n\t"
        "        nop                        \n\t"
        "      .endr                        \n\t"
        "      .if dcycle >= 0              \n\t"
        "        mov \\reg, #dcycle         \n\t"
        "        loop_\\@:                  \n\t"
        "        sub \\reg, #1              \n\t"
        "        bne loop_\\@               \n\t"
        "      .endif                       \n\t"
        "    .endif                         \n\t"
        "  .endm                            \n\t"
        "  fl_delay %[X], r0                \n\t"
        : [X] "I" (X)
        :
        : "r0");
}
```

The macro basically allows for me to do cycle count accurate delays.  So, for example, if in my asm code I write:

```
"  fl_delay 13, r0"
```

it will delay for *exactly* 13 cycles (using register r0 for the loop counter).  This part works fantastically well in a bunch of testing.  The problem comes when I want to make the argument to my macro depend on a template argument (The X, above).  If I (elsewhere) write `delay<13>();` the asm for the generated function looks like:

```
; fl_delay macro definition here 
fl_delay #13, r0
```

The problem is, gnu as's expression parser doesn't like the #.  I suspect the problem is the bit in the macro where, say, I do `.set dcycle, (\\dtime / 3)`.  The `\\dtime` will get replaced with `#13` making that line `.set dcycle, (#13 / 3)` (which I have been able to verify by putting that exact line in some test code, the as error message is the same).

So, I have one of two questions that I need to find an answer to:

- Is there a way for me to get the int value from a template parameter into the asm block *without* the leading #?  (I've tried a bunch of asm constraints but they all put the leading # in there)
- If I can't do the above, is there a way for me to *strip* the leading character of an as .macro argument value?  I've done a bunch of digging but haven't been able to find anything along those lines.

I don't believe there is a way for me to abuse the C preprocessor to do this, as that runs and does its substitutions before any template/C++ parsing is done.

(What I'm writing is some code that has very strict timing requirements, depending on a piece of hardware being talked to - the protocol is pretty much the same for different types of the hardware, the timing is just different.  Because I'm running on hardware with pretty low clock speeds (16-48Mhz), sometimes the delay will be 0-3 clocks, which is short enough to mean that I can't do it in asm, which is why I'm using .macros - because then when there needs to be a delay of 0 (because of the combination of clock speed and hardware timings) nothing gets emitted, if i need a delay of 1, then a single nop gets emitted, etc...)

EDIT:  I have a potential solution, it is ugly, so I'm going to leave the question up here in case folks have another option.  There's a limit to how large my delays can be, so I can basically do something along the following:

```
template<int X> void delay() {
    switch(X) {
      case 0: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 0\n\t"); break;
      case 1: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 1\n\t"); break;
      case 2: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 2\n\t"); break;
      case 3: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 3\n\t"); break;
      case 4: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 4\n\t"); break;
      case 5: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 5\n\t"); break;
      case 6: asm __volatile__ (".set X, 6\n\t"); break;
    }
    asm __volatile__(
        "  .macro fl_delay dtime, reg=r0    \n\t"
        "    .if (\\dtime > 0)              \n\t"
        "      .set dcycle, (\\dtime / 3)   \n\t"
        "      .set dwork, (dcycle * 3)     \n\t"
        "      .set drem, (\\dtime - dwork) \n\t"
        "      .rept (drem)                 \n\t"
        "        nop                        \n\t"
        "      .endr                        \n\t"
        "      .if dcycle >= 0              \n\t"
        "        mov \\reg, #dcycle         \n\t"
        "        loop_\\@:                  \n\t"
        "        sub \\reg, #1              \n\t"
        "        bne loop_\\@               \n\t"
        "      .endif                       \n\t"
        "    .endif                         \n\t"
        "  .endm                            \n\t"
        "  fl_delay X, r0                \n\t"
        :
        :
        : "r0");
}

void loop() { delay<5>(); }
```

Which means that for the `delay<5>();` instantiation, there's a `.set X, 5` that gets emitted just before the rest of my asm block.  It'll be ugly (my delays could be up to 120 cycles) but it will work.

Comment: I have one possible solution, it's ugly, but it'll work for now.  I know that there's a maximum value that my delays will have, so I defined the following macro:

Comment: I don't have an ARM build to try this with, but what about `fl_delay %c[X], r0`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you!  That appears to have done the trick.  I went digging through a bunch of the gcc asm cookbook docs, but don't recall seeing this option anywhere in there.  Does %c just dump the value through without doing any transformations, or does it have other limits?  (Also, since it's a comment, I can't mark your answer as correct)

Comment: (ah, found it buried in here - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html - modifier c -- Require a constant operand and print the constant expression with no punctuation. %c1 2 2 )

Comment: I wasn't sure it *was* correct (which is why I didn't assert it was an answer).  Like I say, I don't have an ARM to test it with.  As for where to find this doc'ed, well, the x86 flags are doc'ed at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers.  That page is for x86-only, but looking in final.c, %cX is supported for all platforms, so it seemed worth trying..